# Can boot, but not login to xubuntu from dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu

I am experiencing problems with my windows 10/Ubuntu dual boot (actually Xubuntu, but I consider these the same).

I have successfully installed Xubuntu on my laptop and was positively able to log in to the grub boot loader, and from there into Xubuntu (which did also work multiple times after turning the computer on and off).

Now, however, I can, however, only get to the user select screen (This is thus not a duplicate of the many "can't find boot loader" questions, as I do can find my boot loader), after correctly typing username and password (I do positively know that this is correct); then the system tries to load further, but never finishes (or did not finish for the hours I let it try to load)

I do can positively load the system (in recovery mode only) as root user and access the file system from the terminal, and from there, I can even start the x-server (using the `startx` command), so I know that everything is still there.

Does anyone know this problem, and how I can fix it such that I can log in normally?

(Please do not suggest that I just always log into my computer in recovery mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be lightdm, which handles the graphical login, disabling lightdm: (as root in recovery mode):

```
systemctl disable lightdm.service
```

And creating `.xinitrc` (in my normal user home folder) containing

```
exec startxfce4
```

Did the trick (I can now log in from CLI, and start Xfce using `startx`, which is what I prefer).